# How to Replace a character in a string which get as an input parameter using SQL stored procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with two columns, one is for storing characters to be replaced and other with the replacement character.

Let rows of my table(each column is separated with '|') are

1. \r\n\r\n | \r\n
2. \r\n | \n

How can I write a stored procedure which accepts string as parameter and replace the characters of the string with these column values.
(Like if a string which contains \r\n then it must be replaced by \n)

I have tried the Cursor method and executed the procedure with the string:-

```
EXEC DBO.SP_REPLACE 'Hello!\r\nThis is for the testing of\r\n\r\nString
replacement\r\nwith characters\r\n\r\nand special characters\r\n'
```

The resuting string :-

```
Hello!\nThis is for the testing of\nString replacement\nwith 
characters\nand special characters\n
```

Actually I wanted to replace 'FIRST OCCURANCE' with a replacement. Once the replacement is done further replacement of the replaced string should be avoided .

So the final expected o/p be like-

```
Hello!\nThis is for the testing of\r\nString replacement\nwith 
characters\r\nand special characters\n
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Hi sir , I am using MS SQL Server Management Studio 18

Comment: Could you provide some of the code you have already attempted? If you haven't already, you should look at STRING_SPLIT - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

Yolu want to use the function REPLACE

REPLACE(yourcolumn, oldstring, newString)

Used like

```
 SET @variable = (SELECT REPLACE(yourcolumn, oldstring, newString) 
 FROM yourTable WHERE something = something)
```

Since you didnt provide alot of details, figuring out the rest should be pretty easy for you.

Because I was bored I also came up with a quick way to detect which replacement you should use as to not get duplicate /n in you final output

```
if object_id('tempdb..#this') is not null drop table #this;

create table #this (col varchar(10), col2 varchar(10));

insert into #this VALUES ('\r\n\r\n','\n'), ('\r\n','\n');

declare @var varchar(125) = 'thisvalue\r\n\r\n\'


set @var = (SELECT REPLACE(@var, Col, col2) FROM (
SELECT t.col, col2, Row_NUmber() OVER (ORDER BY Len(col) desc) As RowNum 
FROM (select @var as Value) x CROSS JOIN #this t
WHERE   x.Value LIKE '%'+t.col+'%') y
WHERE RowNum=1)

select @var
```

Based on your updated requirements this got stupid easy to do:

```
SELECT replace(replace(@string, '\r\n', '\n'), '\n\n', '\n')
```

Comment: Hi Doug Coats, expected results are updated better in the original query, could please check.

Comment: @AbhijithSukkumar see my updated answer (its at the bottom).

Answer (score -2):

I would use a cursor...
you have a table like this

```
 CREATE TABLE DBO.MAPPING (TO_BE_REPLACE VARCHAR(500), REPLACEMENT VARCHAR(500))
 INSERT INTO DBO.MAPPING SELECT '\r\n\r\n','\n'
 INSERT INTO DBO.MAPPING SELECT '\r\n' ,'\n'
```

and this would be the procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DBO.SP_REPLACE

    @TEXT VARCHAR(500)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE 
    @TO_BE_REPLACE VARCHAR(500), 
    @REPLACEMENT   VARCHAR(500)

DECLARE CURSOR_REPLACE CURSOR
FOR SELECT 
        TO_BE_REPLACE, 
        REPLACEMENT
    FROM 
        DBO.MAPPING

OPEN CURSOR_REPLACE;

FETCH NEXT FROM CURSOR_REPLACE INTO 
    @TO_BE_REPLACE, 
    @REPLACEMENT

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @TEXT = REPLACE(@TEXT,@TO_BE_REPLACE,@REPLACEMENT)
        FETCH NEXT FROM CURSOR_REPLACE INTO 
            @TO_BE_REPLACE, 
            @REPLACEMENT
    END;

CLOSE CURSOR_REPLACE;

DEALLOCATE CURSOR_REPLACE;

SELECT @TEXT
END
```

the idea is to run this

```
EXEC DBO.SP_REPLACE 'HELLO\r\n'
```

and get 'HELLO\n'

is this what you are looking for?

edit: iam going to use some of the code from Doug, this time only the first ocurrence.

and yeah... still using a cursor... sorry Doug :), it's just a couple of records

```
CREATE TABLE DBO.MAPPING (TO_BE_REPLACE VARCHAR(500), REPLACEMENT 
VARCHAR(500), PRIORITY_ORDER INT)
  INSERT INTO DBO.MAPPING SELECT '\r\n\r\n','\r\n',1
 INSERT INTO DBO.MAPPING SELECT '\r\n' ,'\n',2
  go

CREATE PROCEDURE DBO.SP_REPLACE

     @TEXT VARCHAR(500)
 AS
 BEGIN
     DECLARE 
    @TO_BE_REPLACE VARCHAR(500), 
    @REPLACEMENT   VARCHAR(500)

 DECLARE CURSOR_REPLACE CURSOR
FOR SELECT 
         TO_BE_REPLACE, 
         REPLACEMENT
     FROM 
         DBO.MAPPING
     ORDER BY PRIORITY_ORDER ASC
 OPEN CURSOR_REPLACE;

 FETCH NEXT FROM CURSOR_REPLACE INTO 
     @TO_BE_REPLACE, 
     @REPLACEMENT

 WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
     BEGIN
        --SET @TEXT = REPLACE(@TEXT,@TO_BE_REPLACE,@REPLACEMENT)
         IF charindex(@TO_BE_REPLACE, @TEXT) <> 0
        SET @TEXT =  stuff(@TEXT, charindex(@TO_BE_REPLACE, @TEXT), len(@TO_BE_REPLACE), @REPLACEMENT)

        FETCH NEXT FROM CURSOR_REPLACE INTO 
            @TO_BE_REPLACE, 
            @REPLACEMENT
    END;

 CLOSE CURSOR_REPLACE;

 DEALLOCATE CURSOR_REPLACE;

 SELECT @TEXT
 END
```

this time if we try

```
EXEC DBO.SP_REPLACE 'Hello!\r\nThis is for the testing 
of\r\n\r\nStringreplacement\r\nwith characters\r\n\r\nand special 
characters\r\n'
```

the output will be

```
Hello!\nThis is for the testing of\r\nStringreplacement\r\nwith 
characters\r\n\r\nand special characters\r\n
```

Comment: cursors are bad when there are better options to do the same thing. shame on you for suggesting it :P <3

Comment: the cursors are your friends Doug :) I see you updated your answer, it's much better now

Comment: Hi Luis , tried the sample code but might need bit more refinement to achieve the expected result . Original post is updated could you please check.

Comment: @AbhijithSukkumar the field PRIORITY_ORDER is to define which one you want to change before

Comment: @LuisGutierrez Actually the expected o/p is not getting , the requirement is to change all occurrence of the special characters or line breaks ,that is if a string contains two \r\n\r\n and two \r\n then it must be replaced with two \r\n and two \n respectively . Actually I meant the First Occurrence in the way that the character already replaced once never be subjected for another replacement.